# Questions every good Struts Developer should be able to answer?

Tags: struts

In the line of [Questions every good Java/Java EE Developer should be able to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-j2ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer)

I would like to ask what are the Questions every good Struts Developer should be able to answer?

Looking forward for some good responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. What is the basic flow of a Struts handled request?

You can find a short description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808585/basic-flow-of-struts/5821096#5821096) and plenty of resources on the web.

*(If you pretend to know Struts then there is no excuse for not knowing number 1)*

Next question is "What is a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)?" (and I'm not kidding; if they fail number 1 they are going to fail to this also, trust me).

### 2. Is ActionForm part of the Model in MVC?

People think the [ActionForm](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html) is part of the Model. They read the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) description and think... Hey!... this is the Model's state, lets move this as parameters all over the Model. Now you have a tight coupling between the Model and the Struts framework.

There are plenty of examples in which the ActionForm properties are mapped 1:1 on DTO POJO objects and those used instead, but people think its a waste of code and time and just pass it along to the Model.

*(Number 2 can can be excused for a junior and is later cured by experience)*

### 3. Do you put your business logic inside the Action class? Why? [Why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762978/the-purpose-of-a-service-layer-and-asp-net-mvc-2/2763071#2763071)

[An Action is an adapter between the contents of an incoming HTTP request and the corresponding business logic that should be executed to process this request](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html)... 'nuff said

*(Number 3 is also cured by experience)*

Answer (score 1):

1. Difference between filters and Interceptors ?
2. Action Chaining
3. classes used as part of struts framework.
4. Validation Plugin
5. struts Configuration.